# multiple assignment and creation with a pointer in golang

Tags: pointers, go

The language spec is way too difficult for me to parse for this simple question, so asking here.

I wrote

```
func take_arg(x *int64) {
    *x,_ = strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1], 10, 64)
}
```

which works.

However, if I try to handle the error

```
func take_arg(x *int64) {
    *x, problem := strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1], 10, 64)
    fix(problem)
}
```

I’m blocked by the compiler, since `non-name *x on left side of :=`.

——

*edit*: It would normally work with `x, problem := …`.

——-

What gives? What should I do?

Comment: `:=` declares a new variable, `*x` is not a valid variable name. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations. *"What should I do?"* a. predeclare `problem` and use `=`, b. use `:=` with valid variable name, then, after error check, set result to arg `*x = validvariablename`.

Comment: @mkopriva but when one of the variables exists and the other doesn’t, `old,new := …` is usually still valid. Just not with `*old`.

Comment: Yes, but `old` and `new` are both valid variable names, what is the point you're trying to make?

Comment: @mkopriva I’ll use your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Notice the name for this expression, "Short variable **declaration**", the *declaration* here is important. In Go a declaration *binds an **identifier** to an "object"* (in case of variable declarations it binds an identifier to the value, in type declarations it binds an identifier to the type, etc.). So when you use `:=` the left hand side must consist solely of valid identifiers (old, new, doesn't matter). With plain assignment expressions `=` the left hand side is specified as a list of *expressions*, which can be identifiers, pointer-indirections, slice indexes, map indexes, etc.

Comment: It is the same as you cannot do `s[i], err := f()`.

Answer (score 0):

`func take_arg(x *int64){...}` **=>** `x *int64` is a pointer of `x int64` value in `heap`.

```
Package: strconv
func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error)
```

return copies (new immutable instance) of `int64` and `error` and you can not to assign return `value` to `x` `pointer`. you have to work with pointer as pointer:

```
func take_arg(x *int64) {
    if i, err := strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[1], 10, 64); err != nil {
        *x = fix(err) // or other action, for example: *x = 777
    } else {
        *x = i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way you can work around this kind of thing is by eliminating the use of `:=`. Just add `var problem error` as the first line of the function, then you can do

```
*x,problem = strconv.ParseInt( os.Args[1],  10,64 )
```

`:=` simply doesn't always make sense.